# How to move key and values from dictionary to list?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the key and value pair of "Brian" to the list "confirmed_users" but can only get the values of said dictionary. How can I get both?

```
state = True
confirmed_users = []
unconfirmed_users = {
    "Brian": {
        "Age": 21,
        "Size": 12,
        "username": "Danny. B"
    }
}
while state == True:
    task_confirming = input("Enter name to be confirmed: ")
    if task_confirming == "Brian":
        for key, value in unconfirmed_users.items():
            confirmed_users.append(unconfirmed_users["Brian"])
        del unconfirmed_users["Brian"]
        print(confirmed_users[0])
        print(unconfirmed_users)
```

*Input:*

```
Brian
```

*Output:*

```
{'Age': 21, 'Size': 12, 'username': 'Danny. B'}
{}
```

Comment: What's the expected output? What do you mean by "get the key and value pair of "Brian""?

Comment: If you want to have a key in `confirmed_users`, it needs to be a dictionary (i.e. that you can look up directly through `Brian`). Otherwise you could append a tuple instead, with both the name and the details: `confirmed_users.append(("Brian", unconfirmed_users["Brian"]))`; or possibly better, make `Brian` part of the dictionary that you append instead.

Comment: It's unclear what your output list should look like. Also, how are you planning to break the *while* loop?

Comment: @rdas  : Ah sorry, I'm trying to get "Brian" and the nested dictionary into the list "confirmed_users", meaning the desired output would be something like "Brian" and then the nested dictionary of Brian. Does that make sense?

Comment: @MatsLindh: Thanks, that's what I meant. What do you mean by your last sentence?

Comment: That `Brian`, if important, should be part of the dictionary as well, so that it would be `{'Age': 21, 'Size': 12, 'username': 'Danny. B', 'name': 'Brian'}` - that way you could just move the dictionary around, since you have that information as part of the dictionary itself and not only as the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several tips:

- you create a new dictionary with the key "Brian" and the corresponding value and append it.
- there is no need for looping over items
- You can also use `pop` to delete the entrance of a dictionary

```py
state = True
confirmed_users = []
unconfirmed_users = {
    "Brian": {
        "Age": 21,
        "Size": 12,
        "username": "Danny. B"
    }
}
while state == True:
    task_confirming = input("Enter name to be confirmed: ")
    if task_confirming == "Brian":
        confirmed_users.append({task_confirming: unconfirmed_users.pop(task_confirming)})
        print(confirmed_users[0])
        print(unconfirmed_users)
```

Comment: Instead of the two strings with "Brian" I'd suggest to replace that with `task_confirming` since the name of the input is related to which entry gets added/removed

Answer (score 0):

Depends a little bit on the format you want.

`confirmed_users.append( (key, value) )`

will add a tuple with (string, dict)

```
("Brian" , {"Age": 21,"Size": 12,"username": "Danny. B"})
```

For adding a dict see Lucas answer.

---

**A note on scalability**: doing a `username in confirmed_users` search where confirmed_users is a list relatively slow.
**Using a dict** with all infos or a set of usernames **will be much faster** due to a hash lookup compared to looking at each element of a list.

---

Sidenote: This will perform a constant action for all items in the list and probably is not what you want ;)

```
for key, value in unconfirmed_users.items():
            confirmed_users.append(unconfirmed_users["Brian"])
```